# Xcode automatically edits my App Icon. How to stop this?

Tags: xcode, icons

I have finished my app in xcode. I have designed an App Icon in photoshop, where I already have applied some sort of glow, which you see in almost every app icon, not knowing xcode would do this for me.

However, my glow + the xcode glow is ugly. How do i stop xcode from editing my app icon?